# c# параметры метода AuthenticateAndContinue

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

В методе `AuthenticateAndContinue(Uri, Uri, ValueSet, WebAuthenticationOptions)` какие два объекта сравниваются в `ValueSet`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Обычно никакие, вызов сводится к:

```
WebAuthenticationBroker.AuthenticateAndContinue(
    new Uri(...),
    new Uri(...),
    null,
    WebAuthenticationOptions.None);
```